# Sum Quantity Between Two Date

Tags: mysql

This code didn't show record. It stop showing sum record when I added date range.

```
SELECT od.Product_ID ,sum(od.Quantity) AS sumqty FROM order_detail od,
 product p, order_r orr WHERE od.Product_ID = p.Product_ID AND
 orr.Order_ID = od.Order_ID AND orr.Order_Date BETWEEN
 '2022/12/23' AND '2022/12/24' GROUP BY p.Product_ID 
ORDER BY sum(Quantity) DESC
```

I want to show sum quantity for each product between two date

Answer (score 0):

Removed "WHERE" and changed to "LEFT JOIN" and also "ON" , below is your original query

```
 FROM order_detail od,
 product p, order_r orr WHERE od.Product_ID = p.Product_ID AND
 orr.Order_ID = od.Order_ID
```

Change to this

```
FROM 
order_detail od
LEFT JOIN product p ON od.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
LEFT JOIN order_r orr ON orr.Order_ID = od.Order_ID
```

Full query

```
SELECT 
    od.Product_ID ,sum(od.Quantity) AS sumqty 
FROM 
    order_detail od
    LEFT JOIN product p ON od.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
    LEFT JOIN order_r orr ON orr.Order_ID = od.Order_ID 
WHERE
    orr.Order_Date BETWEEN '2022/12/23' AND '2022/12/24' 
GROUP BY 
    p.Product_ID 
ORDER BY 
    sumqty DESC
```